# Python some strings to list

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

let's assume that program take these variables;

```py
website = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/"
username = "BestSithInEU"
password = "S0n'X%`2FU`,t!j-"
```

My aim that, I want to store these datas with another class;

```py
class forExample:
    self.header = ["website", "username / email", "password"]
    self.data_list = [website, username, password]

    ### And I'm using this method from csv library
    with open("password.csv", "a", encoding="UTF8", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)

        write multiple rows
        writer.writerows(self.data_list)
```

How can I convert these three variables to list of strings? And also when I use this `self.data_list` I'm getting this output...

| website | username/email | password |
| --- | --- | --- |
| h,t,t,p,s,:,/,/,s,t,a,c,k,o,v,e,r,f,l,o,w,.,c,o,m,/,q,u,e,s,t,i,o,n,s,/ |  |  |
| B,e,s,t,S,i,t,h,I,n,E,U |  |  |

> _csv.Error: iterable expected, not NoneType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The csv writer expects a list of lists.  So

```
self.data_list = [ [website, username, password] ]
```

Comment: yeah you are wright, it solves